# Run QuestDB queries from the command line

Tags: database, questdb

I inserted a data into a table in QuestDB. I want to query now the table and measure its runtime from the console. How I can display it through command?

Answer (score 2):

Easiest is to connect to Web Console at `http://localhost:9000` and query `select * from table_name` or simply `table_name`.

If you want a command line option then you can run `curl` to [export to csv](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/api/rest/#exp---export-data)

```
curl -G --data-urlencode "query=table_name" http://localhost:9000/exp
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always start a webserver using localhost and put curl command like this

```
curl -G --data-urlencode "query=SELECT * FROM emp" http://localhost:port/exp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `psql` terminal based front end for Postgresql to connect to QuestDB via the postgres wire protocol that is exposed on 8812 port by default. If you have psql installed already, you can simply connect as:

```
psql -Uadmin -h localhost -p 8812
```

Or if you have docker, you can also run:

```
docker run -it --rm --network host postgres:13.7-alpine psql -Uadmin -h localhost -p 8812
```

which will launch `psql` in a container and connect to QuestDB using the host network. If you run QuestDB in a container on a different docker network, you would have to use that instead.

Example:

```
$ docker run -d --rm -p 8812:8812 -v /tmp/questdb:/root/.questdb/db questdb/questdb:6.2.1
0a0d4372a4babecf4f6da5a2b726cd16c18667acb770e0db240ce10150f2a236

$ docker run -it --rm --network host postgres:13.7-alpine psql -Uadmin -h localhost -p 8812
Password for user admin: 
psql (13.7, server 11.3)
Type "help" for help.

admin=> \d
             List of relations
 Schema |       Name       | Type  | Owner  
--------+------------------+-------+--------
 public | telemetry        | table | public
 public | telemetry_config | table | public
(2 rows)

admin=> select * from telemetry limit 1;
          created           | event | origin 
----------------------------+-------+--------
 2022-05-25 03:50:43.852890 |   100 |      1
(1 row)

admin=>
```